# Illustration moving but object stationary in Love2d Camera movements

Tags: lua, game-engine, love2d

I am trying to create a game where the main object(a motorcycle) stays stationary but the world around the main object moves (giving the illusion of camera movement. I am able to get the illustration of the ground(the green rectangle at the bottom) to move, but the physical object of the ground remains stationary. You can see in the picture below that the animation of the ground has moved but the motorcycle is still rested on top of it. [image]

If you back the main object back enough, you fall off the back side of the screen.

My code is below

main.lua

```
require("Camera")

function love.load()
  love.physics.setMeter(64) --the height of a meter our worlds will be 64px
  world = love.physics.newWorld(0, 9.81*64, true) --create a world for the bodies to exist in with horizontal gravity of 0 and vertical gravity of 9.81

  objects = {} -- table to hold all our physical objects

  objects.ground = {}
  ground = {}
  ground.x = 1700/2 + Camera.x
  ground.y = 1000-50 + Camera.y
  ground.width = 1700
  ground.height = 50
  ground.body = love.physics.newBody(world, ground.x, 1000-50/2, "static") --remember, the shape (the rectangle we create next) anchors to the body from its center, so we have to move it to (1700/2, 1000-50/2)
  ground.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(ground.width, ground.height) --make a rectangle with a width of 1700 and a height of 50
  ground.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(ground.body, ground.shape, 1); --attach shape to body, give it a density of 1. 
  table.insert(objects.ground, ground)

--creating the motorcycle
  objects.ball = {}  
  objects.ball.x = 1700/2
  objects.ball.y = 1000/2
  objects.ball.width = 100
  objects.ball.height = 50
  objects.ball.body = love.physics.newBody(world, objects.ball.x, objects.ball.y, "dynamic") --place the body in the center of the world and make it dynamic, so it can move around
  objects.ball.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(objects.ball.width, objects.ball.height) --the ball's shape has a radius of 20
  objects.ball.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.ball.body, objects.ball.shape, 1) -- Attach fixture to body and give it a density of 1.
  objects.ball.img = love.graphics.newImage('images/motorcycle.png')

  --initial graphics setup
  love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(0.41, 0.53, 0.97) --set the background color to a nice blue
  love.window.setMode(1700, 1000) --set the window dimensions to 650 by 650
end

function love.update(dt)
  world:update(dt) --this puts the world into motion
  Camera.update(dt) 
end

function love.draw()
  love.graphics.setColor(0.28, 0.63, 0.05) -- set the drawing color to green for the ground

  for _, groundPiece in pairs(objects.ground) do
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", groundPiece.x - 850 - Camera.x, groundPiece.y - Camera.y, groundPiece.width, groundPiece.height) -- draw a "filled in" polygon using the ground's coordinates
  end

  love.graphics.draw(objects.ball.img, objects.ball.body:getX(), objects.ball.body:getY()-(objects.ball.height/objects.ball.img:getHeight())/2, objects.ball.body:getAngle(), objects.ball.height/objects.ball.img:getHeight())

end
```

Camera.lua

```
Camera = {
    x = 0,
    y = 0
}

function Camera.update(dt)

    if love.keyboard.isDown("right") then --RIGHT ARROW BUTTON IS DOWN then
        Camera.x = Camera.x + 5
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
        Camera.x = Camera.x - 5
    end

    if love.keyboard.isDown("up") then
        Camera.y = Camera.y - 5
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown("down") then
        Camera.y = Camera.y + 5
    end

end
```

.

.

.

I have a similar project [here](https://git.cs.usask.ca/sjg970/Line_rider_love_2d.git) where I was able to draw lines on the screen and make them move with Camera movements. I don't understand what I am doing differently in this new project.

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing rectangle based on the offset of camera. But nothing in the physical world knows about your camera. I don't see you ever changing `x` coordinate of the ground (which is static and probably won't let you do that) or of the bike.

So, for physics engine, the relative position of bike and ground does not change at all.

Also, if you expect bike to fall off, you may need to set world's gravity first.

Comment: How do I implement that, I figured that the x coordinate of the ground was not changing, but I don't know why.